# Infinite loop(?) created in Firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am new to web development (or programming in general) and I am writing codes for my personal project. I am writing Firebase cloud function code in Javascript to auto-rotate,compress, and transform into Progressive JPEG once an image is uploaded, using ImageMagick. But the below part of the code is creating an **infinite loop in the backend once an image is uploaded and the function is triggered.**

Any advice on what went wrong? I guess it has to do something with Javascript Promise and I probably will have to return something at the end of each if/else case, but not sure where to look at...can someone help out?

```
if (metadata.autoOrient) { //Check if the image is already rotated and skip auto-rotation
    console.log('This is already rotated');
    return mkdirp(tempLocalDir).then(() => {
        // Download file from bucket.
        return bucket.file(filePath).download({destination: tempLocalFile})
    }).then(() => {
        // Convert the image using ImageMagick.
        return spawn('convert', [tempLocalFile, '-quality', '85', '-interlace', 'plane', tempLocalFile])
    }).then(() => {
        metadata.autoOrient = true
        return bucket.upload(tempLocalFile, {
        destination: filePath,
        metadata: {metadata: metadata}
        })
    }).then(() => {
        // Once the image has been converted delete the local files to free up disk space.
        fs.unlinkSync(tempLocalFile)
        console.log('Compression and PJPEG convsersion successful');
     })
}
else { //Image is not  rotated, thus do all the operations
    return mkdirp(tempLocalDir).then(() => { 
        // Download file from bucket.
        return bucket.file(filePath).download({destination: tempLocalFile})
    }).then(() => {
        // Convert the image using ImageMagick.
        return spawn('convert', [tempLocalFile, '-auto-orient', '-quality', '85', '-interlace', 'plane', tempLocalFile])
    }).then(() => {
        metadata.autoOrient = true
        return bucket.upload(tempLocalFile, {
        destination: filePath,
        metadata: {metadata: metadata}
        })
    }).then(() => {
        // Once the image has been converted delete the local files to free up disk space.
        fs.unlinkSync(tempLocalFile)
        console.log('Auto rotation, compression and PJPEG convsersion successful')
    })
}
```

Comment: what is the problem

Comment: Written in the title and the text: infinite loop is created once the image is uploaded

Comment: tried debbuging the code with break markers? Then you probably can find the point where its starts to loop.

Comment: @J.Ko just change all the code to "async await" syntax, and you can also remove the else statement, as I can see tons of code-duplication. the only row that should be in inside an if-statement is the "return spawn('convert..."

Comment: Please edit the question to show the **entire** code of the Cloud Function.